# Why does this URL go to the wrong place when I submit the form?

Tags: html, forms

```
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<form action="https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=3343995&scope=photos,wall,offline&redirect_uri=http://example.com/vkontakte/auth&response_type=code" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="Auth">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Hello. I've got a problem with this HTML. When i'm clicking the submit button, i expect go to the https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=3343995&scope=photos,wall,offline&redirect_uri=http://example.com/vkontakte/auth&response_type=code link, but instead i go to https://oauth.vk.com/authorize There is no redirects.

Comment: Does it work if you use `action="POST"`? With `action="GET"`, I think the query string in the action URI is replaced with the form fields.

Comment: @Barmar I think you're right, if you look at my answer, putting the query parameters into hidden fields correctly passed them in the URL (and correctly URL encoded them). I'm stealing your idea and putting it into my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your form uses `method="get"`, the query parameters will be erased from your action attribute and form elements will be URL encoded in the URL's query string.

If you can use a POST, you can just change your form to use `method="POST"` and it will work. You should still correctly encode your URL names and values http://jsfiddle.net/9FmtW/3/

If you must use a GET, you have to include your query parameters as hidden fields in your form http://jsfiddle.net/9FmtW/ This has the benefit of correctly URL encoding your query string parameters

```
<form action="https://oauth.vk.com/authorize" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="client_id" value="3343995" />
  <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="photos,wall,offline" />
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect_uri" value="http://example.com/vkontakte/auth" />
  <input type="hidden" name="response_type" value="code" />
  <input type="submit" value="Auth" />
</form>
```

[image]

Your URL contains an URL in it, you need to escape special URL specific characters like `&` and `=`

Comment: It seems like i need to escape "?", can you tell me the escape character for that?

Comment: His example already escapes the question mark.  If you look closely, you can see the `%26` between `auth` and `response`.  Don't try and escape these yourself; use an encoder.

Comment: You don't need to escape the first question mark in the URL, only the question mark in the inner URL. In any case, you can always use `encodeURIComponent("?")` to figure out what the escaped value is. Mmm... your inner URL doesn't have a `?`?

Comment: Even if I left just https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=3343995 it still not working, going to the same place.